# mcrypt_encrypt(): Size of key is too large for this algorithm - Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting below error with Laravel 4 running under WAMP and it seems mcrypt is installed according to PHPinfo

> mcrypt_encrypt(): Size of key is too large for this algorithm

This happens whenever I try to logout of [Laravel Starter Site](https://github.com/andrew13/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site).

Do I need to install or update any library to fix this or is there something else that I need to have a look at?

Comment: Did you follow the instructions and use the command `php artisan key:generate` (step 6) to generate your encryption key? If you generated the key by yourself you might have actually made it too long, which would give this warning.

Comment: Yeah keep the key at 32 characters if you've entered one. (The key is in `app/config/app.php`)

Comment: The key was generated by artisan command in CLI